# ASPxUploadControl: How to make the user add description to a file being uploaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, multifile-uploader

I'm using devexpress multi-file upload as explained [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileUpload.aspx), with almost exactly the same `C#` and `ascx` code. My problem is, I need the user to add a description associated with the file being uploaded. I don't know if this is possible.

(Sorry this is probably a "write me the code" question, but a hint is also really appreciated and will help me a lot)

Comment: From what i understand, you could create an usercontrol which contains you ASPxUploadControl + a textbox + a submit button, and then get the description + file at the same time..

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using one control for uploading the files, and setting `FileInputCount="3"` .. My problem is associating a text box to each of these "inner" file input controls (and these inner controls can be added and removed, as shown in devexpress demo)... Seems what I want to do is not possible :(

Comment: As far as i know, devexpress controls are quite "close" and if you don't the source code version, you can't edit their controls to add custom fields...

Comment: You still can use mutiple ASPxControl, each one with a description textbox... Or don't use ASPxControl at all =)

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [ASPxUploadControl - How to add additional fields to post information along with the uploaded file](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2267) sample from the DevExpress forum.